# Configure Autofs to access windows domain server

Tags: samba, automount

I want to configure **autofs** to access my windows domain server

say my server in win2003 and want to access e$

I am able to access it graphical way

But every time I restart the system I have to mount it again

From graphical way  some time I gets some bus error but if I try again it connects why this error comes

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at my [blog post - Mounting a SMB/CIFS Share as an Automount on CentOS/Fedora/RHEL](http://www.lamolabs.org/blog/6000/one-liner-mounting-a-smbcifs-share-as-an-automount-on-centosfedorarhel/) which shows how to mount Samba share (aka. SMB or CIFS). These are the terms used to identify Windows shares.

The post shows commands for a Fedora Linux system but they should work as is for you on Ubuntu. The steps are as follows:

1. Create a file with the samba share's username/password (/etc/credentials.txt)
2. Install automounter and samba client Ubuntu .deb packages (autofs and samba-client)
3. Add an entry to the /etc/auto.master file for the mount point (/mnt/cifs_share)
4. Create auto.cifs file used by auto.master entry (see example /etc/auto.cifs below)
5. restart automounter service (autofs)

   ```
   share_data  -fstype=cifs,rw,noperm,credentials=/etc/credentials.txt ://192.168.1.1/share_data
   ```

Afterwards the data will show up on /mnt/cifs_share/share_data.

Comment: link is dead, did your blog move?